# Problem with changing properties of :hover

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I'm unable to change background-color of list items to black while :hover.
one the other hand there is no problem with changing color.

```css
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 35px;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0px;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 37px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(81, 59, 192) 26%, rgb(183, 172, 237))
}

.nav li:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
  <li>dolor</li>
  <li>amet</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: my advice is to not use the shorthand of background unless necessary. As for your question just change the background to background-image and set it to none when :hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background color is behind your linear gradient. Change it from `background-color` to just `background` if you want to override the entire background.

Answer (score 1):

The `background` shorthand property sets a number of different properties.

A `linear-gradient` is a type of `background-image` not a `background-color`.

Setting `background-color: black` appears to have no effect because it is covered up by the `background-image`.

Remove the image (`background-image: none`) so you can see the colour.

```css
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 35px;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0px;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 37px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(81, 59, 192) 26%, rgb(183, 172, 237))
}

.nav li:hover {
  background-color: black;
  background-image: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
  <li>dolor</li>
  <li>amet</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Now is working, but when I incrased transition time i can notice of quick flash of white color before it moves to desired color.